# Not able to `replace` content in `style` - where the `html` is stored in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am trying to update the `style` html - by `replacing` a string, but not working. i am not able to get the final updated `html`.

here is my try:

```
var html = "<style>043BF83A8FB24A418DA4248840101D .cls_0 {font:26px 'Arial';}</style><div>testing</div>"

html += $(html).html(function(_,h){
  $(h).find('style').html().replace(/^\w+ (\.\w+)/gm,'$1');
});

console.log(html); //throws the error.
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msnyyphm/2/)

Comment: Why down vote? - the content `html`, i am getting from `server`. for sample i made hard coded.

Comment: It's an error thrown by jQuery, not `console.log`. A tag name starting with a number? Maybe you've to check the server-side code, `043BF83A8FB24A418DA4248840101D` doesn't look like a tag.

Comment: I know that, this is not an element. my question is to pick the `style` element and replace the stuff what i looking..

Comment: But the content of the `style` (i.e. `html` variable) is invalid, jQuery can't parse it and throws an error. If you're passing HTML to `$()`, it must be valid.

Comment: yes. I agree with you.. can you place this as an answer to agree..? Possibly put your implementation. that may make sense.

Comment: I would, but I'm not sure what you're actually trying to replace and with what? What ever it is, you should fix the string itself to be valid HTML before passing it to `$`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me..

```
var html = "<style>043BF83A8FB24A418DA4248840101D .cls_0 {font:26px 'Arial';}</style><div>testing</div>";

var $h = $('<div>'+html+'</div>');
$h.find('style').html(function(_,h){ return h.replace(/^\w+ (\.\w+)/gm,'$1'); });
var updated = $h.html();

console.log(updated);
```

Thanks every one!